# Is there a way to insert values into table that has unique constraint while ignoring rows that are locked

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking

Lets say we have multiple concurrent trasactions inserting into table that has only one field and that field is unique.
Issue is that deadlocks can happen since each insert locks newly inserted row until trasaction is commited (since the field is unique).

So if first trasaction inserts new row(not commited yet) then when another trasaction tries to insert same value it waits for first trasaction. Then deadlock can happen if second transaction already inserted a row that first trasaction will try to insert later on.

What I would like to achive is that second transaction ignores row that its trying to insert if that row is already inserted(locked) by another trasaction.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve the described behavior. PostgreSQL's deadlock detection mechanism will raise an exception in the process that attempts to acquire a sharelock that causes a deadlock. Because neither transaction has been committed, the details of the pending inserts are unavailable to any other processes.

A close approximation of the described behavior can be achieved by retrying the failed inserts with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`. The end result is similar in that the non-conflicting rows from the second transaction will be inserted and the conflicting rows will be ignored; however, some of the ignored rows could be due to conflicts with rows that had already been committed prior to the deadlock.